# Crash issue when moving from background to foreground

Tags: ios, crash, voip, imageloader

I am developing a VOIP application.

Sometimes I am getting a crash issue when moving from background to foreground.

Here is the crash log. MyApp is my app's name.

According to the log, it says "bad food" issue.

> Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

I used LinPhone, XMPP, MoodMeSDK, AFNetworking, and so on.

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
enter code here0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x0000000189f7b224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000189f7b09c mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000189e6cee4 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 540
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000189e6d2e8 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 56
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018a094ee0 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1c368 __78-[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:]_block_invoke + 24
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af417a8 CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_CFPREFSD + 48
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1c2ac -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:] + 264
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1a720 -[CFPrefsPlistSource handleErrorReply:fromMessageSettingKey:toValue:retryCount:retryContinuation:] + 996
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1ba50 -[CFPrefsPlistSource handleReply:toRequestNewDataMessage:onConnection:retryCount:error:] + 184
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1c2d4 -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:] + 304
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1b48c __50-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData]_block_invoke + 92
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018afe1d90 -[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:performBlock:] + 48
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1b3e4 -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData] + 288
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af1cc40 -[CFPrefsPlistSource generationCount] + 560
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af41310 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource handleReply:toRequestNewDataMessage:onConnection:retryCount:error:] + 132
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af41d64 __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:]_block_invoke_3.137 + 80
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018afe1d90 -[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:performBlock:] + 48
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af41d08 __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:]_block_invoke_2.136 + 120
19  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x000000018a076dc4 _os_activity_initiate_impl + 60
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af41c64 __80-[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:]_block_invoke.134 + 120
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af417a8 CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_CFPREFSD + 48
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af419dc -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 180
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af422b8 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyDictionary] + 384
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af40784 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 68
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018afdab18 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 64
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018afe0614 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 40
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af4386c __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 268
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af43130 normalizeQuintuplet + 360
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af43754 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 104
30  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018afe0578 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 300
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af48824 ___CFBundleCopyUserLanguages_block_invoke + 44
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000189e569a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000189e576cc dispatch_once_f + 56
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af48028 _CFBundleCopyLanguageSearchListInBundle + 724
35  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af213cc _copyQueryTable + 60
36  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018af20a18 _copyResourceURLsFromBundle + 396
37  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aebb888 _CFBundleCopyFindResources + 1236
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aebb3a8 CFBundleCopyResourceURL + 60
39  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aec48ec CFBundleGetLocalInfoDictionary + 120
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aec483c CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey + 40
41  CFNetwork                       0x000000018b713658 StrictSecurityPolicy::InitializeProcessGlobalATSState() + 84
42  CFNetwork                       0x000000018b713574 StrictSecurityPolicy::CopyATSState() + 40
43  CFNetwork                       0x000000018b8080f8 -[__NSCFURLSessionConfiguration initWithDisposition:] + 720
44  CFNetwork                       0x000000018b807804 +[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration] + 56
45  MyApp                           0x0000000100513bcc 0x100064000 + 4914124
46  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000189a026b0 call_load_methods + 184
47  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000189a03840 load_images + 76
48  dyld                            0x00000001025fdfec dyld::notifySingle(dyld_image_states, ImageLoader const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList*) + 496
49  dyld                            0x000000010260db30 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 348
50  dyld                            0x000000010260cb74 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 136
51  dyld                            0x000000010260cc30 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 84
52  dyld                            0x00000001025fe490 dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 220
53  dyld                            0x00000001026026bc dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3640
54  dyld                            0x00000001025fd044 _dyld_start + 68
```

Comment: did you try putting an exception breakpoint and check where you are getting the crash. Also, post the relevant code.

Comment: this is only occur on TestFlight build, when I tried test on device which connected to Xcode, there is no issue like something.

Comment: did you try setting release mode and test?

Comment: how can I check it? where?

Comment: This way you can edit your scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORBJL.png. Change the Run's Build configuration to `release` from `build` and then try to run.

Comment: I made new configuration for Appstore version. there are Debug, Release, AppStore configuration. how can I check whether AppStore configuration is release mode or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150574/discussion-between-priyal-and-james-chan).